# Tailwind value is causing a white border when switching to dark mode

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind and react in this project. The problem here is that `mb-10` in the form is causing a white border at the bottom.

```
<section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">
  <div class="py-8 lg:py-4 px-4 mx-auto max-w-screen-md">
    <h2 class="mb-4 text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-center text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
      Contact Us
    </h2>
    <p class="mb-8 font-light text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 sm:text-xl">
      Got a technical issue? Want to send feedback about a beta feature?
      Need details about our Business plan? Let us know.
    </p>
  </div>
  <form action="#" class="space-y-8 px-10 mb-10 ml-14">
    <div>
      <label
        for="email"
        class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"
      >
        Your email
      </label>
      <input
        type="email"
        id="email"
        class="shadow-sm w-2/4  bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
        placeholder="name@flowbite.com"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label
        for="subject"
        class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"
      >
        Subject
      </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="subject"
        class="block w-2/4  p-3 text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
        placeholder="Let us know how we can help you"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="sm:col-span-2">
      <label
        for="message"
        class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400"
      >
        Your message
      </label>
      <textarea
        id="message"
        rows="6"
        class="block w-2/4 p-2.5 text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg shadow-sm border border-gray-300 focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500"
        placeholder="Leave a comment..."
      ></textarea>
    </div>
    <button
      type="submit"
      class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center mr-3 md:mr-0 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
    >
      Poslat Zprávu
    </button>
  </form>
</section>
```

I've tried wrapping the form with a `div` with `class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900"` but it still doesn’t seem to be working.

Comment: Where exactly is the "mb-10" you're referring to? There are a lot of classes and elements in the code you've provided. Also, it would be great if you could get rid of any irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The White Things below form wasn't border. It's background color of body tag.
You can fix it my simply replacing `mb-10` with `pb-10`. Make sure You know the difference between `padding`, `margin` and `border` in CSS Layout. Next time, You could use Browser DevTools to inspect which is it.